# Adding elements of a set in Alloy

Tags: modeling, alloy

For the set time: {1,2,3,4}, how can we compute the sum of the elements in the set in Alloy? Is there a way to use Alloy's add function for sets?

```
pred addTime[time: set Time]{
    add[time] = 10
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sum a set of Int with the `sum` operator

```
 let s = 1 + 2 + 3 | 6 = sum s
```

However, if you use Time as in Jackson's book then you cannot add them since they are not Int's. So I am a bit confused what you want to model?